# Money is no object

Tags: phrase-usage

I have found on [FL](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9076/money-is-no-object) the English expression: “money is no object”, with OP’s following explanation:
“it means you will spend however much necessary to get what you want”.

If I said this phrase in my langage everyone would think I meant:
"Money is no object but mean”, where object = goal, purpose, scope, etc., and mean is the way to get/achieve the object.

I wonder whether the above expression "money is no object” may have this connotation in English like in my language and if not how could we say this in English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I say that "X is no object," that means "X is not important **to me**, especially not **in comparison to something else** I am after.

So, if I'm feeling generous, and I want to pay for lunch, I would **not** say: "Money is no object." That wouldn't be a good context to fit the expression.

However, if someone has kidnapped my daughter, and they are demanding a ransom, I might say, "I don't care how much they want – money is no object," meaning, "Money is nothing compared to the safety of my daughter."

It's a phrase usually reserved for when the stakes are high.

Comment: Linguistically, this is more closely related to "objection" than to the usual meaning of "object".

Answer (score 1):

This is good one.

Anything *[be no object](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/be-no-object)* means it is trivial, of less significance or no problem with it. Maybe, because you either ignore it or have *a lot of it*!

> [Money is no object](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Money+is+no+object) i.e. money is not a problem.

This'll make it clear:

> *"Show me the best car in your showroom. Ah, money is no object."* [I'm richest, don't worry... the cost does not matter here but get me what I want'.

Comment: Thank you! So far so good. What about later on? That you shouldn’t make a goal in your life of achieving money for they are merely a modality to achieve a goal? Does this concept exist in English or not?

Comment: @LucianSava no no! That would not mean it. When you say *money is no object* it means the cost is not an issue or problem for whatever thing you buy or dream of. We often get an essay to write on - What would you like to do if money is no object. There, we need to express ourselves doing anything as money does not matter there. Like I can say in that essay that I would like to OWN this universe (as money is no object) to have everything under control of mine. I'd then punish the culprits and criminals without any bias or being influenced!